# Thunderbird : email notification and unity-panel icon

Tags: 14.04, icons, thunderbird, notification, gmail

Problems:

1. The main icon in unity-panel doesn't change when I receive an email.
2. There is no pop up.

System setting:

- Thunderbird is open.
- Sound notification works.
- Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher integration 1.3.1" in list of extensions.
- Thunderbird 38.5.1
- Ubuntu 14.04
- My account is on Gmail.

[image]

Update1:
I tried to install Web apps application with these instructions

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
```

It doesnt work.Now the number of unread emails even doesnt show up in the icon below the screen.

Update:
I tried to install popper as an alternative but it doesnt support after  Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I update the question

Comment: Can someone  suggest an alternative to program to fix the problem?

Comment: why negative vote? at least comment about your reason. What is the problem with this question ?

Comment: tell the output of :  cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service

Comment: It's shown up since 38.2, evidently.... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1491249

Comment: @juggernaut1996 output is quiet long with strange characters . are you sure it is correct?

Comment: mybad... i meant : cat /usr/share/upstart/xdg/autostart/indicator-messages.desktop

Comment: [Desktop Entry]  <br />  
 
Type=Application
Name=Indicator Messages
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Hidden=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-messages

Comment: If you can show me an alternative to have notification, it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Popper work again on Ubuntu 14.04 with the following actions (see [bug 1683516](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/1683516/comments/3) ):

```
sudo apt-get install libindicate-gtk3 libindicate5 python-indicate python-support

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/ralf.hersel/rhersel-ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/p/popper/popper_0.31.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i popper_0.31.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb 

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-messages/libindicator-messages-status-provider1_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
sudo dpkg -i libindicator-messages-status-provider1_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-messages/indicator-messages_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
sudo dpkg -i indicator-messages_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-gtk2_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i indicator-messages-gtk2_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
```

Then for MATE - `mate-tweak` -> *Panel (Interface) -> Enable indicators*.

Then *Applications -> Internet -> Popper* - set account settings.

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-indicators
[ /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-indicators ]
Package: indicator-messages
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: indicator-messages-gtk2
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libindicator-messages-status-provider1
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: popper
Pin: version 0.31.3-0ubuntu1 
Pin-Priority: 1337

EOF
```

For Ubuntu 16.04 you can use [my solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/965156/66509) posted here on AskUbuntu.