# No new mail notification for main icon of Thunderbird in unity-panel

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, email, notification, gmail

Thunderbird is open but the main icon in unity-panel doesn't show that I received an email. I would like that icon change when I receive an email. Take a look at screenshot.

[image]

When I receive an email, there is a notification sound but no pop up.
I am using Thunderbird 38.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and my account is on Gmail.

Also there is another problem that I like to fix: desktop notification doesn't work.

Comment: maybe an add-on can fix the problem?

Comment: I combined two questions in one : http://askubuntu.com/questions/726389/thunderbird-email-notification-and-unity-panel-icon and now I delete this question

Answer (score 0):

Check for the Thunderbird add-on with the name:

"Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher integration 1.3.1"

If it's there and activated, then check the notification settings in Thunderbird.

Comment: I have "Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher integration 1.3.1" in list of extensions and notification settings are all fine.