# Is it possible to make Popper mail notification working on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 (MATE and Unity)?

Tags: 16.04, unity, 18.04, email, mate

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I used [Popper](https://launchpad.net/%7Eralf.hersel/+archive/ubuntu/rhersel-ppa?field.series_filter=precise) as e-mail checker.

[image: Popper main window]

It supports POP/POP3 and IMAP without and with SSL.

[image: Popper accounts]

Has Thunderbird integration.

[image: Popper indicate]

and integrates into `indicator-messages`:

- [image: no new emails] - no new e-mails
- [image: new emails] - got new e-mails
  [image: New Emails notification]

Is it possible to make Popper mail notification working on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 (MATE and Unity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The result will look like as in screenshot from Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS:

> [image: Popper on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

## Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (running MATE or Unity)

See comment on [bug 1683516](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/1683516/comments/5).

You can do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libindicate-gtk3 libindicate5 python-indicate \
python-gnomekeyring python-notify

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-support/python-support_1.0.14ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-support_1.0.14ubuntu2_all.deb

wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/ralf.hersel/rhersel-ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/p/popper/popper_0.31.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i popper_0.31.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb 

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-messages/libindicator-messages-status-provider1_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
sudo dpkg -i libindicator-messages-status-provider1_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-messages/indicator-messages_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
sudo dpkg -i indicator-messages_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-gtk2_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
sudo dpkg -i indicator-messages-gtk2_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
```

Then for MATE - `mate-tweak` *-> Panel (Interface) -> Enable indicators*.

Then *Applications -> Internet -> Popper* - set account settings.

Then pin installed packages:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-indicators
Package: indicator-messages
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: indicator-messages-gtk2
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libindicator-messages-status-provider1
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: popper
Pin: version 0.31.3-0ubuntu1 
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: python-support
Pin: version 1.0.14ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

EOF
```

Reboot and login back.
That is all. You got `indicator-messages` working again.

## Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (running MATE or Unity)

You can do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libindicate-gtk3 libindicate5 python-indicate \
python-notify libpango1.0-0
    
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-support/python-support_1.0.14ubuntu2_all.deb
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/ralf.hersel/rhersel-ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/p/popper/popper_0.31.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-messages/libindicator-messages-status-provider1_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-messages/indicator-messages_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-gtk2_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-messages/libindicator-messages-status-provider1_0.6.0-0ubuntu2_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-gnomekeyring_2.32.0+dfsg-3_`dpkg --print-architecture`.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

Then *Applications -> Internet -> Popper* - set account settings.

Then pin installed packages:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-indicators
Package: indicator-messages
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: indicator-messages-gtk2
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libindicator-messages-status-provider1
Pin: version 0.6.0-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: popper
Pin: version 0.31.3-0ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: python-gnomekeyring
Pin: version 2.32.0+dfsg-3
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: python-support
Pin: version 1.0.14ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

EOF
```

Reboot and login back.
That is all. You got `indicator-messages` working again.

## Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS

Popper is installable with some hacks, but does not work anymore.