# Linux e-mail notifier

Tags: email, update-notifier

I have Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit.
Please advise me how to be notified on my e-mails
without continuously checking out e-mail boxes.
Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say which email client you are using - for example, I use Thunderbird and I receive notifications in the top bar of any emaiis received, software updates etc.

Comment: What you need is this list from the Arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#Mail_notifiers

Answer (score 3):

Good things to try are:

- [MailNag](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag) (fork of [Popper](https://askubuntu.com/q/965155/66509)), it is installable by

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pulb/mailnag
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mailnag
  ```
- Mozilla Thunderbird with [BirdTray](https://github.com/gyunaev/birdtray), installable by

  ```
  sudo apt-get install thunderbird birdtray
  ```

  BirdTray minimizes Thunderbird on start and then monitor its mail folders to indicate number of new e-mails and show notification about new mails.

Comment: Evolution, the standard GNOME e-mail client, also informs about incoming mails via notifications. There is also an additional package, `evolution-indicator`, that displays notifications even when Evolution application is not currently running.

Comment: @raj your comment seems like an answer. Would you care to post it as one?

Answer (score 0):

Evolution, the standard GNOME e-mail client, also informs about incoming mails via notifications. There is also an additional package, `evolution-indicator`, that displays notifications even when Evolution application is not currently running.

Comment: I use alltray with evolution for the mail indicator as it hasn't worked properly for me in Ubuntu 16 and 18